# Image looses quality in java swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I have used every popular way to display picture in java swing, but with every method the picture losses quality even without any kind of resizing. No matter what format GIF, PNG, JPEG the picture doesn't appear like the original one outside of the code. I have tested swing code to display images on other computers, it works fine on them but not on my computer.

These are the methods I have tried so far:

*Note- To keep the things short the code below is for example only.*

1.Graphics method

```
public class mainClass extends Canvas {
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Toolkit t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Image i = t.getImage(getClass().getResource("monsters.png"));
        g.drawImage(i, 0 , 0, this);
    }
    public static void main(String []args){
        mainClass m = new mainClass();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(m);
        frame.setSize(800,800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

2. Simple JLabel setIcon method

```
   ImageIcon gif = new ImageIcon("Loading2 (1).gif");
   label.setIcon("gif");
```

3. Scaled JLabel setIcon method

```
public ImageIcon create(ImageIcon i ,int x,int y){
    Image img = i.getImage();
    Image imgScaled = img.getScaledInstance(x,y,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    return new ImageIcon(imgScaled);
}
```

Comparison:

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQJRG.png)

[JavaOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mrd0q.png)

Comment: In the Toolkit code you should have loaded the image outside the `paint` once. BTW always add `@Override` to detect typos = the method never being called.

Comment: Are you running on Windows 10 or 11 with monitor scaling > 100%?

Comment: Get your Graphics object for image painting from the Canvas, this.getGraphics() because the code is in a Canvas class. Put the graphics paint code in a nominal named method and use @Override on both update and paint methods (really you should not bother with the paint() method , just the update , just call the initial nominal method you make to paint) and simply put the call for the painting method in them. see "also" public void repaint(long tm) in the api docs.